# Why is Montana warmer than Wyoming?

Tags: meteorology, climate, temperature

The National Climatic Data Center (NCDC) data shows the [mean temperature from 1971-2000 for Montana was 5.97°C (42.74°F) and Wyoming's was 5.54°C (41.98°F)](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/psd/data/usclimate/tmp.state.19712000.climo).

Montana is at a higher latitude, so this is surprising.

Comment: Wyoming's mean elevations (2040 m) is higher than Montana's mean elevations (1040 m).

Comment: The difference between them isn't very significant...

Comment: @Paul How large a temperature difference would be significant?

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned in the comments, [the 1km difference in average elevation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_elevation) of Wyoming in comparison to Montana plays a major role, as from the website [Wyoming State Climate Office](http://www.wrds.uwyo.edu/sco/wyoclimate.html),

> Because of its elevation, Wyoming has a relatively cool climate.

However, there is a bit more to it than that, the presence of numerous valleys

> provide ideal pockets for the collection of cold air drainage at night. Protecting mountain ranges prevent the wind from stirring the air, and the colder heavier air settles into the valleys often sending readings well below zero.